# How to call a method from another class in groovy?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

For Instance, I have a class like this:

```
class firstOne{

    ....
    def A (){

    }

}

class secondOne{

    // I need to call and use method A from class firstOne
    // even I get error if I try to follow Java like calls
    // firstOne method = new firstOne();
    // method.A()   
}
```

I already tried http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scripts+and+Classes and http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans but no way. Any kind of suggestion or examples would be really helpful.

Comment: What does this have to do with grails? Also, capital letter methods are best avoided

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: your statements need to be in a code block rather than the class block

Comment: It's inside a geb automation script. It shows a general error: " org.spockframework.runtime.ConditionNotSatisfiedError". I will post a more details about the error within few minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see any problem in this:

```
class FirstOne {

    def a() {
        println "a"
    }
}

class SecondOne {

    def b() {
        new FirstOne().a()
        println "b"
    }
}

new FirstOne().a()
println("")
new SecondOne().b()
```

Output:

```
a
a
b
```

Comment: thanks man, it was beneficial to tackle my problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to Groovy/Grails:

```
firstOne first = new firstOne()
first.A()
```

Also you should capitalize the first letter of classes, but not methods (as is best practice in Java).

Comment: I already tried this and did not work! This is not 100% Groovy/Grails but working on totally Java+Groovy!

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun Then there is some part missing from your question.  I see you've made a comment about including more details, so perhaps those will help.